# SQL Server 2008, Pivot based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am using SQL Server 2008, and I have a simple table:

```
Product.SKU
Product.Model
Product.Color
Product.Size
```

With the following 9 rows:

| SKU | Model | Color | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PC | Blue | Normal |
| 2 | PC | Red | Normal |
| 3 | MAC | Silver | Normal |
| 4 | PC | Green | Normal |
| 5 | Mac | Blue | Normal |
| 6 | Phone | Blue | Normal |
| 7 | PC | Blue | Large |
| 8 | PC | Red | Large |
| 9 | MAC | Silver | Large |

I want to create a SQL view to pivot other possible color options for each model/Size combo, that would display like the following:

```
View.Model
View.Size
View.SKU
View.Color
View.ALTSKU1
View.ALTColor1
View.ALTSKU2
View.ALTColor2
View.ALTSKU3
View.ALTColor3
etc. etc.
```

| Model | Size | SKU | Color | AltSKU1 | AltColor1 | AltSKU2 | AltColor2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PC | Normal | 1 | Blue | 2 | Red | 4 | Green |
| PC | Large | 7 | Blue | 8 | Red | NULL | NULL |
| Mac | Normal | 3 | Silver | 5 | Blue | NULL | NULL |
| Mac | Large | 9 | NULL | NULL | Blue | NULL | NULL |
| Phone | Normal | 6 | Blue | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Please review some other sql server questions and look at how to present and explain your sample data - see [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can easily pivot on multiple columns using built-in functionality, but you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function together with conditional aggregation to achieve the desired effect.

Something like:

```
WITH CTE_Data AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Model, Size ORDER BY SKU) AS RowNumber
    FROM #Data
)
SELECT
    CD.Model, CD.Size
    , SKU       = MAX(CASE WHEN CD.RowNumber = 1 THEN CD.SKU   END)
    , Color     = MAX(CASE WHEN CD.RowNumber = 1 THEN CD.Color END)
    , AltSKU1   = MAX(CASE WHEN CD.RowNumber = 2 THEN CD.SKU   END)
    , AltColor1 = MAX(CASE WHEN CD.RowNumber = 2 THEN CD.Color END)
    , AltSKU2   = MAX(CASE WHEN CD.RowNumber = 3 THEN CD.SKU   END)
    , AltColor2 = MAX(CASE WHEN CD.RowNumber = 3 THEN CD.Color END)
FROM CTE_Data CD
GROUP BY Model, Size
ORDER BY Model, Size
```

Yielding the following result:

| Model | Size | SKU | Color | AltSKU1 | AltColor1 | AltSKU2 | AltColor2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MAC | Large | 9 | Silver | null | null | null | null |
| MAC | Normal | 3 | Silver | 5 | Blue | null | null |
| PC | Large | 7 | Blue | 8 | Red | null | null |
| PC | Normal | 1 | Blue | 2 | Red | 4 | Green |
| Phone | Normal | 6 | Blue | null | null | null | null |

See [this db<.fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WEMkZsWV) for a demo.

To allow for an unknown number of alternate SKUs, you can use dynamic SQL to generate a select that matches the maximum number of SKUs per Model/Size combination.

Here is the version using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @AltSkuItemsTemplate VARCHAR(MAX) = '
        , AltSKU<N1>   = MAX(CASE WHEN CD.RowNumber = <N2> THEN CD.SKU   END)
        , AltColor<N1> = MAX(CASE WHEN CD.RowNumber = <N2> THEN CD.Color END)
'

DECLARE @AltSkuItems VARCHAR(MAX)= ISNULL((
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(
        @AltSkuItemsTemplate
        , '<N1>', CONVERT(VARCHAR, RN.RowNumber - 1))
        , '<N2>', CONVERT(VARCHAR, RN.RowNumber))
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Model, Size ORDER BY SKU) AS RowNumber
        FROM #Data
    ) RN
    WHERE RN.RowNumber >= 2
    ORDER BY RN.RowNumber
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '')

--PRINT @AltSkuItems

DECLARE @SqlTempate VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    WITH CTE_Data AS (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Model, Size ORDER BY SKU) AS RowNumber
        FROM #Data
    )
    SELECT
        CD.Model, CD.Size
        , SKU       = MAX(CASE WHEN CD.RowNumber = 1 THEN CD.SKU   END)
        , Color     = MAX(CASE WHEN CD.RowNumber = 1 THEN CD.Color END)
<AltSkuItems>
    FROM CTE_Data CD
    GROUP BY Model, Size
    ORDER BY Model, Size
'

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLACE(@SqlTempate, '<AltSkuItems>', @AltSkuItems)

--PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

The `FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE` in the above is a technique for concatenating multiple results into a single string. The `.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)')` extracts the text from the resulting XML (and cleanly handles any special characters, such as carriage returns).

See [this updated db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WDGe0CtY) for a demo of both of the above.

Comment: Updated above with dynamic SQL example.

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed it. Thank you for the detailed explanation, @T-N !